# Can't compile simple C++ code using boost trivial log with filters

Tags: c++11, boost

I am trying to use boost log with simple code from: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/trivial_filtering.html. I am using codeblock 13.12 on Windows 8.1 with cpu: AMD-A8. Code is below:

```
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

using namespace std;

void init()
{
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main()
{
    init();
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:
C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_convertible.hpp: In instantiation of 'struct boost::detail::sp_enable_if_convertible':
**C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:76:5:   required by substitution of 'template boost::intrusive_ptr::intrusive_ptr(const boost::intrusive_ptr&, typename boost::detail::sp_enable_if_convertible::type) [with U = boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_value::impl]'**
C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/log/attributes/attribute_value.hpp:95:20:   required from here
C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_convertible.hpp:81:37: warning: base class 'struct boost::detail::sp_enable_if_convertible_impl' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]
In file included from C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/log/attributes/attribute_value_set.hpp:27:0,
                 from C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/log/core/record.hpp:21,
                 from C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/log/core/core.hpp:23,
                 from C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/log/core.hpp:20,
                 from C:\Workspace\FileReconciliation\main.cpp:3:

The command CodeBlock used to compile is:
mingw32-g++.exe -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -Weffc++ -pedantic -g -IC:\Java\boost_1_55_0 -Iinclude -c C:\Workspace\FileReconciliation\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o

Regardless where I put this include:

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
```

It always give me the same error message. I tried boost 1_55_0, 1_59_0 and 1_60_0. If I remove init(), it compiles without error.

I googled a lot and can't find an answer. Could someone please help? 
Thanks a lot
gt

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error, to me.

Comment: It is error. On the end of Build log in CodeBlock:
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 8 second(s))
3 error(s), 190 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 8 second(s))
Also there is no obj\Debug\main.o created.

Answer (score 0):

Missing namespace definition for `logging`.

You will need the following statement after the #include code block.

```
// Alias for shorter namespaces.
namespace logging = boost::log;
```

Comment: See the complete code sample: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_trivial_flt.cpp

Comment: Hi gxy, thank you for your response.
I copied the code from your link and add 2 lines: 
#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp>

Comment: Hi gxy, thank you for your response.
I copied the code from your link and add 2 lines: 
#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp>

but I still get 11 errors: 
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 16 second(s))
11 error(s), 364 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 16 second(s))

Comment: C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/fusion/iterator/equal_to.hpp:81:9:   required by substitution of 'template<class Iter1, class Iter2> typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::and_<boost::fusion::is_fusion_iterator<Iter1>, boost::fusion::is_fusion_iterator<Iter2> >, bool>::type boost::fusion::iterator_operators::operator==(const Iter1&, const Iter2&) [with Iter1 = mpl_::assert_; Iter2 = mpl_::assert_]'
I have included the header files, it still complains. Also the compilation takes forever. I have to stop it manually. Otherwise it never stops.

Comment: C:\Java\boost_1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:76:5:   required by substitution of 'template<class U> boost::intrusive_ptr::intrusive_ptr(const boost::intrusive_ptr<U>&, typename boost::detail::sp_enable_if_convertible<U, T>::type) [with U = boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_value::impl]'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using: "-std=gnu++11", instead of "-std=c++11".
It took me a few days...